# EF core add migrations in ASP.net core multilayered architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, command-line, entity-framework-core

I have recently started ASP.net core project with multilayered architecture, where CatalogDbContext and StartUp class in different layers:

[image]

I want to add migrations to DroneStore.Data layer. I change in command prompt current directory to ../DroneStore.Data/ and add command:

**dotnet ef migrations add Initial**

And got an error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'CatalogDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

When I change current directory to ../DroneStore.Web/ and add this command i got error:

> Your target project 'DroneStore.Web' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'DroneStore.Data'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly

Any suggections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Change your currend directory in command prompt to:

**cd ../DroneStore.Data/**

2) Add to command -s option with path to StartUp project folder:

**dotnet ef migrations add Initial -s ../DroneStore.Web/**

Comment: And what `-s` option do?

Comment: `-s`  the startup project to use. See [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/commands/cli-commands)

Comment: Why not `-p` option?

Comment: `-p` points to project where you add migrations, but `-s` option always points to project where your StartUp class situated. So actually instead of change your current directory in command prompt you can write dotnet ef migrations add Initial -p ..\DroneStore.Data\ -s ..\DroneStore.Web\

Comment: Why OP needs to provide StartUp project?

Comment: The startup project is the one that the EF tools build and run. The EF tools have to execute application code at design time to get information about the project, such as the database connection string and the configuration of the model.